# Can a single imperial item be used to complete several imperial assignments?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Several Imperial Assignments contain the same item, albeit with a different goal quantity/inventory.  If I achieve the lower of the two inventories first and "complete" that assignment, will my inventory go back to zero on the other assignment?

Answer (score 3):

No, it cannot be used more than once. You will lose the required stock when you complete one assignment.

Prior to the upgrade, you could move the levels around with level movers, and that would change what item was called for in the assignments.  I do not know if that works now.

Answer (score 2):

No, your inventory does not go back down to zero once you complete an Imperial assignment. I'm quite certain of that.

2 out of the 3 assignments for me require the same component, and when I finished the one with lower requirements, my stock did not go down to zero, and I only had to stock up a few more to complete the second assignment.

In other words, each assignment uses up only the stock that is asked for, and anything left over is still available for other assignments.

**Before** using the components (System Scan) for Assignment 2:
[image]

[image]

**After:**
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the stock was not used?  It should only drop to zero if you had the exact amount needed for the assignment.

Comment: No, I meant if Assignment 1 needs components of 20 System Scans and Assignment 2 needs 35 System Scans for example, and you have 40 System Scans on hand. You will be left with 20 System Scans (and only need accumulate 15 more for a total of 35 to then complete Assignment 2) should you choose to complete Assignment 1, or you will be left with 5 System Scans on hand if you choose to complete Assignment 2 instead. I think the poster of the question is worried that his System Scans on hand will be reset to zero every time he completes an assignment, and his excess inventory goes to waste.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear.  I was not referring to items which you had excess, but rather the "last" item in the assignment (e.g. the Sith Droid in your screen shots.)  You have answered my question which is essentially that you have to choose which assignment you want to use your inventory on first.